# How to get values from a spinner populated from a cursor

Tags: android, database, spinner

I've populated my spinner as this:

```
DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);
    dbConnector.open();
    Cursor c = dbConnector.raw("SELECT _id, nombrecasa FROM casa");
    startManagingCursor(c);
    String[] from = new String[]{"nombrecasa"};
    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
    casaSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.casaspinner);
    casaSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    dbConnector.close();
    }
```

And when I try to get the value as:

```
String idcasa   = casaSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

it only returns this:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40539880
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spinner has taken a `SimpleCursorAdapter` as an adapter, of which its dataset is a `Cursor`. When you select an item on the spinner, you've only moved the cursor to a specific row and when you call `getSelectedItem()` you're still requesting for the dataset object - which is still a cursor object. to do what you're trying you can simply call:

```
c.getString(1);
```

once your selection has been made. For something a little more fundamentary illustrative of what i said.

```
((Cursor) casaSpinner.getSelectedItem()).getString(1);
```